# C# AppBar Application overlapping fullscreen applications

Tags: c#, .net, windows, forms

I've managed to develop an AppBar which stays in top of the screen, and maximized windows don't overlap with it.
Now, i want tohave the same behavior with applications running in fullscreen mode : for exemple if i run chrome or ie in fullscreen my appbar stays on top but it overlaps the browser's page content.

here is the appbar code :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }


    #region APPBAR

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct RECT
    {
        public int left;
        public int top;
        public int right;
        public int bottom;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct APPBARDATA
    {
        public int cbSize;
        public IntPtr hWnd;
        public int uCallbackMessage;
        public int uEdge;
        public RECT rc;
        public IntPtr lParam;
    }

    enum ABMsg : int
    {
        ABM_NEW = 0,
        ABM_REMOVE = 1,
        ABM_QUERYPOS = 2,
        ABM_SETPOS = 3,
        ABM_GETSTATE = 4,
        ABM_GETTASKBARPOS = 5,
        ABM_ACTIVATE = 6,
        ABM_GETAUTOHIDEBAR = 7,
        ABM_SETAUTOHIDEBAR = 8,
        ABM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED = 9,
        ABM_SETSTATE = 10
    }

    enum ABNotify : int
    {
        ABN_STATECHANGE = 0,
        ABN_POSCHANGED,
        ABN_FULLSCREENAPP,
        ABN_WINDOWARRANGE
    }

    enum ABEdge : int
    {
        ABE_LEFT = 0,
        ABE_TOP,
        ABE_RIGHT,
        ABE_BOTTOM
    }

    private bool fBarRegistered = false;

    [DllImport("SHELL32", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    static extern uint SHAppBarMessage(int dwMessage, ref APPBARDATA pData);
    [DllImport("USER32")]
    static extern int GetSystemMetrics(int Index);
    [DllImport("User32.dll", ExactSpelling = true,
        CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern bool MoveWindow
        (IntPtr hWnd, int x, int y, int cx, int cy, bool repaint);
    [DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern int RegisterWindowMessage(string msg);
    private int uCallBack;

    private void RegisterBar()
    {
        APPBARDATA abd = new APPBARDATA();
        abd.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(abd);
        abd.hWnd = this.Handle;
        if (!fBarRegistered)
        {
            uCallBack = RegisterWindowMessage("AppBarMessage");
            abd.uCallbackMessage = uCallBack;

            uint ret = SHAppBarMessage((int)ABMsg.ABM_NEW, ref abd);
            fBarRegistered = true;

            ABSetPos();
        }
        else
        {
            SHAppBarMessage((int)ABMsg.ABM_REMOVE, ref abd);
            fBarRegistered = false;
        }
    }

    private void ABSetPos()
    {
        APPBARDATA abd = new APPBARDATA();
        abd.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(abd);
        abd.hWnd = this.Handle;
        abd.uEdge = (int)ABEdge.ABE_TOP;

        if (abd.uEdge == (int)ABEdge.ABE_LEFT || abd.uEdge == (int)ABEdge.ABE_RIGHT)
        {
            abd.rc.top = 0;
            abd.rc.bottom = SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize.Height;
            if (abd.uEdge == (int)ABEdge.ABE_LEFT)
            {
                abd.rc.left = 0;
                abd.rc.right = Size.Width;
            }
            else
            {
                abd.rc.right = SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize.Width;
                abd.rc.left = abd.rc.right - Size.Width;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            abd.rc.left = 0;
            abd.rc.right = SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize.Width;
            if (abd.uEdge == (int)ABEdge.ABE_TOP)
            {
                abd.rc.top = 0;
                abd.rc.bottom = Size.Height;
            }
            else
            {
                abd.rc.bottom = SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize.Height;
                abd.rc.top = abd.rc.bottom - Size.Height;
            }
        }

        // Query the system for an approved size and position. 
        SHAppBarMessage((int)ABMsg.ABM_QUERYPOS, ref abd);

        // Adjust the rectangle, depending on the edge to which the 
        // appbar is anchored. 
        switch (abd.uEdge)
        {
            case (int)ABEdge.ABE_LEFT:
                abd.rc.right = abd.rc.left + Size.Width;
                break;
            case (int)ABEdge.ABE_RIGHT:
                abd.rc.left = abd.rc.right - Size.Width;
                break;
            case (int)ABEdge.ABE_TOP:
                abd.rc.bottom = abd.rc.top + Size.Height;
                break;
            case (int)ABEdge.ABE_BOTTOM:
                abd.rc.top = abd.rc.bottom - Size.Height;
                break;
        }

        // Pass the final bounding rectangle to the system. 
        SHAppBarMessage((int)ABMsg.ABM_SETPOS, ref abd);

        // Move and size the appbar so that it conforms to the 
        // bounding rectangle passed to the system. 
        MoveWindow(abd.hWnd, abd.rc.left, abd.rc.top,
            abd.rc.right - abd.rc.left, abd.rc.bottom - abd.rc.top, true);
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == uCallBack)
        {
            switch (m.WParam.ToInt32())
            {
                case (int)ABNotify.ABN_POSCHANGED:
                    ABSetPos();
                    break;
            }
        }

        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }

    protected override System.Windows.Forms.CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.Style &= (~0x00C00000); // WS_CAPTION
            cp.Style &= (~0x00800000); // WS_BORDER
            cp.ExStyle = 0x00000080 | 0x00000008; // WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW | WS_EX_TOPMOST
            return cp;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        RegisterBar();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RegisterBar();
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is your precise question? What did you try to do and why it didn't work?

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply, i want IE ,when ran in fullscreen mode, to use only a limited area o the screen and dont overlap the appbar application.

Comment: The code above is the only thing i tried for the moment. it works but only prevent maximized apps from overlapping the appbar. i want to have the same behavior with the fullscreen mode.